# How to exclude some string patterns when using filter on pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

## dataframe

```
df.columns=['ipo_date','l2y_gg_date','l1k_kk_date']
```

## Goal

- return dataframe with columns name containing `_date` except for `ipo_date`.

## Try

- `df.filter(regex='_date&^ipo_date')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a [negative lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973436/15497888):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1, 21).reshape((5, 4)),
                  columns=['ipo_date', 'l2y_gg_date', 'l1k_kk_date', 'other'])

filtered = df.filter(regex=r'(?<!ipo)_date')
print(filtered)
```

Sample `df`:

```
   ipo_date  l2y_gg_date  l1k_kk_date  other
0         1            2            3      4
1         5            6            7      8
2         9           10           11     12
3        13           14           15     16
4        17           18           19     20
```

`filtered`:

```
   l2y_gg_date  l1k_kk_date
0            2            3
1            6            7
2           10           11
3           14           15
4           18           19
```